# .append() adds html as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm using javascript to add html to my 's.
I made a loop that goes around all projects there are. There are multiple projects and in every project there are multiple pictures.

The first part creates the first projecttitle within a div that gets an id(the projectname) and the first pictures.

```
$( ".projectbeeldcontainer" ).append(


'</div>'+
     '<h1 class="projecttitel" id="'+name+'">'+name+'</h1>'+
     '<div class="row dashboardrow" id="'+name+'id">'+
      '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
        '<div class="thumbnail">'+
            '<a href="/w3images/lights.jpg">'+
              '<img src="projectbeelden/'+name+'/'+decodeURI(image)+'" class="img-rounded">'+
            '</a>'+
            '<div class="caption tags">'+
                '<p>titel van project</p>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>';

    );
```

After this, the script will check if the projectname of the next image allready exists. If it does exist (because we added it with the code above), then it will insert a new div inside of the project div we created:

```
document.getElementById(name+'id').append(


'<div class="col-sm-2">'+
        '<div class="thumbnail">'+
            '<a href="/w3images/lights.jpg">'+
              '<img src="projectbeelden/'+name+'/'+decodeURI(image)+'" class="img-rounded">'+
            '</a>'+
            '<div class="caption tags">'+
                '<p>titel van project</p>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>'




      );
```

The problem i have now is that the first line of code successfull creates the div's and the image. The second code works for 98%.

It does recognise the div with the id and puts the content in it. But the problem is that it adds quotes before my first line and after. So it looks like it thinks it's a string and not html.

So it literally adds "<div ..." on my page.

Can anyone help me please? Sorry for the bad spelling and grammar.

Comment: You are using dom element's [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method, not jquery's [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which appends the given string as it is

Comment: Right, it's a bit perplexing why you use jQuery in the first code and native DOM methods in the second.

Comment: Use jQuery `$('#'+name+'id').append(`

Comment: Why not use jQuery for the second version also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use innerHTML instead of append.

```
document.getElementById(name+'id').innerHTML += "<div> put your html </div>";
```

Append adds a textNode. Better way is something like this by generating it and inserting into the DOM:

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Put yout HTML"));
document.getElementById(name+'id').appendChild(el);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Zeller. I know i'm not doing it the "clean" way. innerHTML does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are literally telling it to append a string to the DOM, you are not creating an element that you can insert.

If you wrap the html that you are trying to append in the jQuery wrapper `$('<div class="col-sm-2">....</div>');`, then it will be treated by jQuery as an a jQuery object and should then be able to be inserted in the manor that you need.

Answer (score 0):

This work to me

```
var stringToHTML = function (str) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
        return doc.body;
    };    
$( ".projectbeeldcontainer" ).append(stringToHTML('<p>text</p>'))
```

Answer (score -1):

DEMO

```js
var insertData = '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
        '<div class="thumbnail">'+
            '<a href="/w3images/lights.jpg">'+
              '<img src="" class="img-rounded">'+
            '</a>'+
            '<div class="caption tags">'+
                '<p>titel van project</p>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
      '</div>';
 document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = insertData;
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: This replaces the contents, it doesn't append.

Comment: @markus answer will append it thus up voted:) n you are right it will replace the html.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of "<" and ">" in your code. Browser will not recognize this string as html code and print it as a plain text.